# SELECT an additional column from another table based on a value between 2 other values

Tags: sqlite, join, correlated-subquery

I have 2 pretty basic tables:

Table: user

```
id|name|exp
 1|test|270
 2|foo |510
```

Table: level

```
level|exp
    1|0
    2|100
    3|250
    4|500
```

I want to have a pretty simple query, which gives me my level, according to my provided exp-value. Obviously I started with something like:

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = 1
```

But then I failed on building a query with a join, which compared my value and finds the "next" level it should return. So in my example, my row with `id = 1` should return 3, while `id = 2` should return 4.

My expected output would be a table like this:

```
id|name|exp|level
 1|test|270|3
 2|foo |510|4
```

Do I even have to join here or is there anything similar? Can I have a subselect? Do I have to check somehow with `BETWEEN`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do this would be with a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT u.*,
       (SELECT l.level FROM level l WHERE u.exp >= l.exp ORDER BY l.exp DESC LIMIT 1) AS level
FROM user u;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/HJIAULD1).

Answer (score 1):

This is a way to do it using `group by` and `inner join` :

```
SELECT u.*, max(l.level) as level
from users u
inner join levels l on u.exp >= l.exp
group by u.id
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/y3GHJo1b)